# How to do code generation with modern Python packaging?

Tags: python, code-generation, packaging, pep517

I've been trying to wrap my head around modern Python packaging, and one of the things I still can't find anything clear about is how to do build-time codegen (so e.g. in-source data files get compiled to code file during build, and those code files get packaged in the sdist or wheel).

From [what PEP517 seems to imply](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#in-tree-build-backends), I feel like it requires implementing a custom build backend:

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = "local_backend"
backend-path = ["backend"]
```

and then that's supposed to do some things and delegate to some existing build backend for the actual bundling?

Are there examples available? I tried looking around, but most projects seem to use pyproject.toml in addition to setup.py, and I've yet to find one which uses pyproject.toml *exclusively* and has a non-trivial build step.

It also somewhat feels like there's a billion PEP517 build frontends which are *also* backends? Is that real or am I misunderstanding?